# torch precision causes sum to ignore small float

Tags: pytorch, floating-point, precision, torch, floating-accuracy

I am encountering an unexpected from `pytorch` where the sum ignores a `1e-6` number :

```
test_tensor = torch.tensor([10, 20, 10, 1e-6])
print(torch.sum(test_tensor) == torch.sum(test_tensor[0:-1]))
```

and the output is :

```
tensor(True)
```

this is troublesome for me as I need the difference between the two tensors to be none zero (strictly positive)
Is there a way to fix this issue.

Comment: The single precision (IEEE-754 `binary32`) number that is closest to the mathematical result is 40. In other words, 40 and 40.000001 are indistinguishable in single precision due to limited finite precision. Chose a data type with higher precision if the difference between 40 and 40.000001 matters, e.g. double precision (IEEE-754 `binary64`).

Comment: building on @njuffa's comment `test_tensor = torch.tensor([10, 20, 10, 1e-6], dtype=torch.double)` should work for you